# How to get an answer when the bounty doesn't work?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, bounty

I have recently asked a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2079165/how-many-ways-are-there-to-color-the-vertexes-of-a-n%C3%97n-square-with-four-colors). First it has some meaning problems but now it doesn't. It didn't get any answers so I set a bounty but it doesn't work how can I get an answer? I really need an answer so I want a way to get an answer as soon as possible.

Comment: This is, to some extent, related: [How effective are bounties?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/20155)

Comment: Since you wrote that the bounty did not bring any answer, you might be interested in my suggestion to collect somewhere unresolved bounties. 
For details see [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/23647) and [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/43020/2016/7/26). However, it will definitely help you to *get answer as soon as possible*. (It is more of a long-term project. Moreover, it's still basically a test - many users are unaware of this chatroom.)

Comment: For one thing, as the comments to your question note, you could clarify what you're asking.  That's a comment specific to the question that you've used as an example in this (meta) question, not necessarily a general comment to the overall issue that you've raised here.

Comment: Another suggestion: adjust your expectations. There is no guarantee of speed, and being antsy about your question only 5 days in, before your bounty is even over is not an overwhelming display of patience.

Comment: Just wondering why you **really need** an answer to that question...